# Call-graph analysis: How to find out if method CA#ma eventually calls CB#mb

Tags: java, eclipse, call-graph

Say I have a java project consisting of too many classes. There is an entry-point method that calls other methods defined in other classes, which in turn call other methods.

Given an entry point and target candidate(s), I want to see all possible subsets of the static call-graph leading from entry to target.

I am looking for a tool, ideally as an Eclipse plugin, possibly taking advantage of JDT. But using the .java sources is OK, too. There is no reflection trickery involved, so it's OK to miss those dynamic dependencies.

The question I want to answer is, if and how can any one of a set of methods get invoked by another method, however far the call-stack may be.

Comment: Are you searching for an Eclipse plugin / technique to do that or do you want advice on how to write that plugin?

Comment: I am looking for something ready-to-use. Question updated.

Comment: Seems like what you want is a cross reference, "CA#ma can call CB#mb" presumably for all mb which overload CA#ma.x such that CA#ma contains x(....).   You're ok with not tracing methods called through simulated function objects?

Comment: @IraBaxter right, for these I would need breakpoints or stack trace sampling or, to be sure, instrumented code like with tracing profilers. But I am just looking for statically generated subgraphs, knowing they might miss some more fancy dynamic calls (that don't happen in the project I am looking at).

Comment: I have tools that parse Java and do static name resolution.  That gives you basic a-calls-b relations. These same tools also have support for computing the transitive closure of that, which seems to be what you want.  They are commercial.   Do you want more information?

Comment: I may sound cheap now, but the task at hand here does not really justify a commercial tool that does a lot more than I need. I looked at the semanticdesigns site and I am not sure which of the tools applies here, but they look like overkill for my limited purposes, so we would most likely not purchase.